# Custom number picker which can display : 0 1 0?

Tags: android, android-number-picker

With the default android Number Picker, when there is only 0 and 1 inside it, the UI doesn't react properly (freeze or glitch).
Is there a possibility to extends from Number Picker to have as displayed Values [0,1,0] ?Thanks!!

Comment: there no custom data picker which display 3 digit.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) what would be the solution? Hm, maybe a custom viewpager?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom value using NumberPicker. You can use something like this:

Layout:

```
    <android.widget.NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/custom_np"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Logic:

```
NumberPicker numberPicker = view.findViewById(R.id.custom_np);
...
// Define the text to be displayed in NumberPicker
String[] texts = {"0", "1"};
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(texts.length - 1);
numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(texts);
numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

Comment: Yup, I know that. But have you tried your specific code here ? (with the array texts = {"0", "1"}) it doesn't act like if there was more numbers...

Comment: What did you really want to achive? did you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33053895/4758255