# BindingAdapter for Numberpicker

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I'm implementing a "Wheel picker" using `NumberPicker` as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662187/2145504).

I'm also using data binding and trying to populate the view at the XML.

Here is what I've done:

```
    @BindingAdapter("maxValue")
internal fun NumberPicker.customSetMaxValue(max: Int){
  maxValue = max
}

@BindingAdapter("minValue")
internal fun NumberPicker.customSetMinValue(min: Int){
  minValue = min
}

@BindingAdapter("values")
internal fun NumberPicker.customSetDisplayedValues(data: List<String>){
  displayedValues = data.toTypedArray()
}
```

```
<NumberPicker
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:entries="@array/dosage_type"
          app:maxValue="2"/>
```

Despite of this, I get: `error: attribute maxValue (aka com.company.project.dev:maxValue) not found`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try getting rid of the `internal` keyword.

Comment: @CommonsWare tried. Unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: OK... try making the parameters nullable (`Int?`, `List<String>?`) and see if that helps. I have [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/blob/v0.6/T15-Display/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/BindingAdapters.kt) in a sample project that is working.

Comment: It didn't work either. I think the issue is about how it is binded into the XML. @CommonsWare how do you do it in your projects? I'm using `app:maxValue="2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using app:maxValue="2"

That is not a binding expression. Even if your value is a constant, you need to have it be in a binding expression:

```
app:maxValue="@{2}"
```