# android listview how to focus nearest item after sliding

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-listview, slide

I want to the ListView to focus automatically on the item in the list closest to the frame after the scroll event. I've been searching that for hours but couldn't find. The thing that happened:

[image]

The thing that i want to happen:

[image]

How can i do?

Comment: I think you can achieve this using Wheel  picker -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053765/how-to-make-a-wheel-picker

Answer (score 0):

The NumberPicker is perfectly made for that.
Put that lines of code in your `class.java`.

```
 String[] days = new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4"};
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(days.length-1);
picker.setDisplayedValues(days);
```

And your `XML` layout could look like this:

```
<NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/reminder_picker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

That's the most elegant way to achieve a scroll date `widget`.